# Encoding 4 byte UTF-8 character to JSON from Rails produce invalid character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, utf-8, afnetworking, httparty

I have a web service in rails (3.2.19) that encode a JSON to be read by some iOS or Android apps.
The json might contain any characters, but it seems to fail every time I use a 4 bytes UTF8 character such as : it produce instead `\uf4a9` aka ``.

In rails console the character is **correctly** displayed but when i retrieve the answer in iOS with AFNetworking or with HTTParty, it fails.

Here is my code sample to retrieve the faulty JSON:

```
puts HTTParty.post( 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/login',
:body => { :login => 'antoine',
           :password => 'thisisnotmypassword',
         }.to_json,
:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json' })
```

And to encode the JSON:

```
format.json { render json: json_reponse } #json_response is a Hash.
```

Sending other UTF-8 characters works well, for exemple: `ضصيتحضصتحخـ`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I used

`JSON::dump(obj))`

Answer (score 4):

Your web service is encoding the JSON incorrectly. It looks like you're not using the standard JSON encoder, since [as of Rails 3.2.13, the Unicode characters are passed through](http://omegadelta.net/2013/04/28/changes-to-how-rails-3-2-13-and-4-0-encodes-unicode-in-json/) (that is, you shouldn't be seeing *any* `\u1234`-type encoding.)

That said, if you want to maintain the old encoding, try switching from `object.to_json` to `JSON.generate(object, :ascii_only => true).` (More details in the link in the 1st paragraph.)

Answer (score 0):

Oj can also do the job:

```
Oj.dump(obj, mode: :compat)
```

You will have to add `oj` it to your gem list